AWS CloudFormation Adding Security Group
Below is a sample of how our team creates new EC2 instances using CloudFormation with AWS. I'm just getting started myself with AWS, but one problem I have is when I need to create a new Security Group for an EC2 instance that has been created using CloudFormation, I'm being told I can't associate it with the EC2 in code and I have to create the security group in code then go into the console and associate it there. If I try to associate it in code it will recreate the EC2 instance? Is what I'm being told correct? Is there a way I can create a new SG in code and link it to an EC2 instance without doing any damage to the existing EC2 image? Thank you.
Resources:
  SERVERLaunchTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: EC2GSSADBUR
      LaunchTemplateData:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !ImportValue windows-standard-sg
          - !ImportValue windows-standard2-sg
        IamInstanceProfile: 
          Name: !ImportValue defaultInstanceProfile
        MetadataOptions:
          HttpPutResponseHopLimit: 2
          HttpTokens: required
        Monitoring:
          Enabled: true

  SERVER01Alias:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Alias
    Properties:
      AliasName: alias/SERVER01
      TargetKeyId: !Ref SERVER01KMS 
  SERVER01KMS:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      Enabled: true
      EnableKeyRotation: true
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: Enable IAM User Permissions
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root
            Action: kms:*
            Resource: '*'
  SERVER01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0960ad9be9axxxxxx  
      InstanceType: m5.xlarge
      KeyName: SERVER01-keypair
      UserData: !Base64 |
        Rename-Computer SERVER01
        Restart-Computer
      BlockDeviceMappings: 
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeType: gp2
            VolumeSize: 100
            Encrypted: true
            KmsKeyId: !GetAtt SERVER01KMS.Arn
        - DeviceName: /dev/sdb
          Ebs:
            VolumeType: gp2
            VolumeSize: 500
            Encrypted: true
            KmsKeyId: !GetAtt SERVER01KMS.Arn
      SubnetId: subnet-08bba3360bxxxxxx     
      PrivateIpAddress: x.x.x.66
      Ipv6Addresses: 
        - Ipv6Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:66
      PropagateTagsToVolumeOnCreation: "true"
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: SERVER01
      LaunchTemplate: 
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref SERVERLaunchTemplate   
        Version: !GetAtt SERVERLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber


If something is created using infrastructure as code, you should maintain it using infrastructure as code. Adding a security group to an existing template, then deploying that template, should not change the EC2 instance.
The best way to ensure your change won't delete anything is to create a change set with CloudFormation. It will tell you what it's going to change, create, and delete. If you don't like what the change is going to do simply delete the change set. Be careful not to delete the whole stack like I did once, but I think AWS has moved the delete buttons since then.
